# APIv3 Rest URL ... Could not load the settings file

Tags: api, rest

I have a test instance started  a day ago of CiviCRM running on Amazon EC2 using the bitnami version (https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm/cloud) which uses Drupal 7.72 and runs CiviCRM 5.27.4

I added an api_key through MySQL for the correct user id and read the CIVICRM_SITE_KEY from civicrm.settings.php which I found at /bitnami/drupal/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php

Running APIv3 through the CiviCRM console (http://mysite/civicrm/api3#explorer) works and generates an example query url to use for REST. However, when I substitute in the keys and put the query in my browser address bar I get:
"Could not load the settings file at: /bitnami/drupal/modules/contrib/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php"

What can I change to make sure that the civicrm.settings.php file is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this is a temporary fix. Would be interested to know a final solution:
In the path /bitnami/drupal/modules/contrib/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php
the '//' is interpreted as '/' so the file being looked for is:
/bitnami/drupal/modules/default/civicrm.settings.ph

Well, there is no default directory in /bitnami/drupal/modules so I created it and inside I put a symlink to the correct location of civicrm.settings.php
cd /bitnami/drupal/modules/default
ln -s /bitnami/drupal/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php civicrm.settings.php

With that the example REST query works fine.